# Bundeling jre with java Swing app on Launch4j

Tags: ubuntu, java, jre

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to bundle the jre path with my java app in launch4j so that the app can run anywhere without the need of java. But as I run the .exe file of the app on another computer, it says jre is absent although I copied entire jre folder inside my project folder(with bin and lib).
I am unable to troubleshoot the problem as I can't figure out where the problem is.
Please help!!

Comment: You need to set the java environment variables

Comment: How can I do that? Please tell!

Comment: Answered on [so], see [How to set Java environment path in Ubuntu - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612941/how-to-set-java-environment-path-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I want to run the app on a computer on which java is not present! Actually i set jre min. version 1.0.0 on launch4j so when i try to run it on another computer it says min 1.0.0 jre is required! My sole purpose is to run the app without the need of java

Comment: You still need to set the environment variables so that the JRE can be found.

Comment: You cannot run a java app without installing at least the JRE.

Comment: So do I need to set envronment variables in set env. tab of launch4j?So what path will I give there?

Comment: Please read the previous link I gave you ...

Comment: Yes I have used that reference but it didn't work. Still it says min 1.0.0 jre required

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand! How to remove!! That is the only error that is curbing me

Comment: Then you haven't set up Java correctly. Go and read the instructions again.

Comment: [Launch4j - Cross-platform Java executable wrapper](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs_es.html)

Comment: I have checked everything! I have also downloaded the seperate jre for my project and gave its path relative to executable file in the bundle path, but still the app doesn't run on another windows computer. It still says missing JRE!